# Screen command set shell title to current host name

Tags: gnu-screen

I would like to know how can I set the shell title to the name of host we are currently logged into. 
My scenario is like this. 
I log into host  A then open up screen
and create several new windows and ssh to different hosts on those windows.
So I would like screen title at the bottom to show the current host it is in.
[image: im talking about this particular string at the bottom]

Comment: I'm using terminator

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to use the `LocalCommand` feature of `ssh`. With this method, an escape sequence to change the terminal's title will be printed after a successful connection to a remote host.

Edit or create `~/.ssh/config` to include something like:

```
Host *
    PermitLocalCommand yes
    LocalCommand printf '\033]0;%%s\007' '%h'
```

The downside of this method is that the title remains changed after logging out of the remote server. You can get around that with:

```
printf '\033]0;%s\007' "$(uname -n)"
```

If you want to automate this, you could use a function:

```
lssh () {
    /path/to/ssh "$@"
    printf '\033]0;%s\007' "$(uname -n)"
}
```

---

This answer assumes that your terminal emulator uses the [same escape sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) as XTerm. If this is not the case, you should check the documentation for your specific terminal emulator.

One caveat in the case of GNU screen is that a single terminal window may contain several virtual windows. In that case, you could use a different escape sequence (`\033k%s\033\\`) to set the internal title of a single virtual window.